# Alternative to header("Content-type: text/xml");

Tags: php, wordpress

Is there an equivalent to the following:

```
header("Content-type: text/xml");
```

I'm using Google Maps with Wordpress and I get the "headers already sent" error. I've gone through all the files and taken out all the whitespace but the error still appears so just wondering if there was another way of doing the code above.

This is the error:

```
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/medicom/public_html/mapping/wp-content/themes/default/header.php:11) in /home/medicom/public_html/mapping/wp-content/themes/default/new-version1.php on line 45
```

And this is my page - http://www.mediwales.com/mapping/test/

```
<?php
/**
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Default_Theme
 * Template Name: Latest Version
 */
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head profile="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="<?php bloginfo('html_type');?>; charset=<?php bloginfo('charset');?>" />
<title><?php wp_title('&laquo;', true, 'right');?></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url');?>" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/markerclusterer.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo('pingback_url'); ?>" />
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&v=2&key=ABQIAAAAdnbfsmnsdaFBmEZfsJEmiWC7p0LLmMBSsffI9l26I_viUYjW7vRG7TlO-sRQKR0B_YAsP2VnDdVgsr4Aegvksdw" type="text/javascript"></script>
<?php if ( is_singular() ) wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' ); ?>
<?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>
<body <?php body_class(); ?> onload="load()" onunload="GUnload()">
    <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
        <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <div id="body">
<?php
require("database.php");
function parseToXML($htmlStr)
{
$xmlStr=str_replace('<','&lt;',$htmlStr);
$xmlStr=str_replace('>','&gt;',$xmlStr);
$xmlStr=str_replace('"','&quot;',$xmlStr);
$xmlStr=str_replace("'",'&#39;',$xmlStr);
$xmlStr=str_replace("&",'&amp;',$xmlStr);
return $xmlStr;
}
// Opens a connection to a MySQL server
$connection=mysql_connect (localhost, $username, $password);
if (!$connection) {
  die('Not connected : ' . mysql_error());
}
// Set the active MySQL database
$db_selected = mysql_select_db($database, $connection);
if (!$db_selected) {
  die ('Can\'t use db : ' . mysql_error());
}
// Select all the rows in the markers table
$query = "SELECT * FROM markers WHERE 1";
$result = mysql_query($query);
if (!$result) {
  die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}
header("Content-type: text/xml");
// Start XML file, echo parent node
echo '<markers>';
// Iterate through the rows, printing XML nodes for each
while ($row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
  // ADD TO XML DOCUMENT NODE
  echo '<marker ';
  echo 'name="' . parseToXML($row['name']) . '" ';
  echo 'address="' . parseToXML($row['address']) . '" ';
  echo 'lat="' . $row['lat'] . '" ';
  echo 'lng="' . $row['lng'] . '" ';
  echo 'type="' . $row['type'] . '" ';
  echo '/>';
}
// End XML file
echo '</markers>';
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    var iconBlue = new GIcon();
    iconBlue.image = 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_blue.png';
    iconBlue.shadow = 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png';
    iconBlue.iconSize = new GSize(12, 20);
    iconBlue.shadowSize = new GSize(22, 20);
    iconBlue.iconAnchor = new GPoint(6, 20);
    iconBlue.infoWindowAnchor = new GPoint(5, 1);
    var iconRed = new GIcon();
    iconRed.image = 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_red.png';
    iconRed.shadow = 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png';
    iconRed.iconSize = new GSize(12, 20);
    iconRed.shadowSize = new GSize(22, 20);
    iconRed.iconAnchor = new GPoint(6, 20);
    iconRed.infoWindowAnchor = new GPoint(5, 1);
    var customIcons = [];
    customIcons["restaurant"] = iconBlue;
    customIcons["bar"] = iconRed;
    function load() {
      if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {
        var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map"));
        map.addControl(new GSmallMapControl());
        map.addControl(new GMapTypeControl());
        map.setCenter(new GLatLng(47.614495, -122.341861), 13);
        GDownloadUrl("phpsqlajax_genxml.php", function(data) {
          var xml = GXml.parse(data);
          var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
          for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
            var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
            var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");
            var type = markers[i].getAttribute("type");
            var point = new GLatLng(parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
                                    parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
            var marker = createMarker(point, name, address, type);
            map.addOverlay(marker);
          }
        });
      }
    }
    function createMarker(point, name, address, type) {
      var marker = new GMarker(point, customIcons[type]);
      var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address;
      GEvent.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        marker.openInfoWindowHtml(html);
      });
      return marker;
    }
    //]]>
  </script>  
  <div id="map" style="width: 500px; height: 300px"></div>
</div>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
<?php wp_footer(); ?>
</body></html>
```

Comment: There is no equivalent. The fix is to find out where there is content that is forcing the headers to be sent. Have you heard of the Byte Order Mark? That might be your problem. It could also be something obvious like Wordpress sending content before you call `header()`.

Comment: Which line does it point to in the "headers already sent" error? You should get an exact file name and line number

Comment: @Pekka I've tried to solve this problem before and just gave up! Updated my question with more info anyways.

Comment: `.../themes/default/header.php:1` - that is the place where the first output takes place, you'd have to see whether you can get your own header call in before that

Comment: @Pekka If I put it in before line 1 then would it just hit the Wordpress header call and flag that up? Is there a way to combine the two?

Comment: Are you calling `get_header()` in `new-version1.php`?

Comment: @Nick Yes, should I put my code above that in the template?

Comment: No.  You probably don't need to call `get_header` if you are going to set your own headers and output.

Comment: @Nick It's all within a Wordpress template so I need the get_header

Comment: including `get_header()` is not a requirement for a wordpress template.  Because you are outputting `xml` including `get_header()` will always break it.

Comment: @Nick I think it's going over my head a bit! I've moved the header and footer into the one template, still get the same error (although line numbers are different). I've updated my question with the actual code.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Now I see what you are doing.  You cannot send output to the screen then change the headers.  If you are trying to create an XML file of map marker and download them to display, they should be in separate files.

Take this

```
<?php
require("database.php");
function parseToXML($htmlStr)
{
$xmlStr=str_replace('<','&lt;',$htmlStr);
$xmlStr=str_replace('>','&gt;',$xmlStr);
$xmlStr=str_replace('"','&quot;',$xmlStr);
$xmlStr=str_replace("'",'&#39;',$xmlStr);
$xmlStr=str_replace("&",'&amp;',$xmlStr);
return $xmlStr;
}
// Opens a connection to a MySQL server
$connection=mysql_connect (localhost, $username, $password);
if (!$connection) {
  die('Not connected : ' . mysql_error());
}
// Set the active MySQL database
$db_selected = mysql_select_db($database, $connection);
if (!$db_selected) {
  die ('Can\'t use db : ' . mysql_error());
}
// Select all the rows in the markers table
$query = "SELECT * FROM markers WHERE 1";
$result = mysql_query($query);
if (!$result) {
  die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}
header("Content-type: text/xml");
// Start XML file, echo parent node
echo '<markers>';
// Iterate through the rows, printing XML nodes for each
while ($row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
  // ADD TO XML DOCUMENT NODE
  echo '<marker ';
  echo 'name="' . parseToXML($row['name']) . '" ';
  echo 'address="' . parseToXML($row['address']) . '" ';
  echo 'lat="' . $row['lat'] . '" ';
  echo 'lng="' . $row['lng'] . '" ';
  echo 'type="' . $row['type'] . '" ';
  echo '/>';
}
// End XML file
echo '</markers>';
?>
```

and place it in `phpsqlajax_genxml.php` so your javascript can download the XML file.  You are trying to do too many things in the same file.

Answer (score 3):

No. You can't send headers after they were sent. Try to use hooks in wordpress

Comment: How would I use hooks to do that? I've also updated my question with some more info.