# MySQL to XML message header issue

Tags: php, mysql, xml

I have a problem with generating xml from MySQL which appears to be related to the message header **header("Content-type: text/xml");**  [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11083084/alternative-to-headercontent-type-text-xml) refers to this issue but does not solve the problem in my case. The post refers to the 2007 GMap example, not  [the updated 2009 version](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch_v3#creating-the-map)

Here is the code in full...

```
$center_lat = $_GET["lat"];
$center_lng = $_GET["lng"];
$radius = $_GET["radius"];
// Start XML file, create parent node
$dom = new DOMDocument("1.0");
$node = $dom->createElement("markers");
$parnode = $dom->appendChild($node);

// Opens a connection to a mySQL server
$connection=mysql_connect ("99.99.99", "abcdefg", "zzzzzz");
if (!$connection) {
  die("Not connected : " . mysql_error());
}

// Set the active mySQL database
$db_selected = mysql_select_db("xxxxxxx", $connection);
if (!$db_selected) {
  die ("Can\'t use db : " . mysql_error());
}

// Search the rows in the markers table
$query = sprintf("SELECT address, name, lat, lng, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians('%s') ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians('%s') ) + sin( radians('%s') ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM markers ",
  mysql_real_escape_string($center_lat),
  mysql_real_escape_string($center_lng),
  mysql_real_escape_string($center_lat),
  mysql_real_escape_string($radius));
$result = mysql_query($query);

if (!$result) {
  die("Invalid query: " . mysql_error());
} 
// - !!!! This is the problem line !!!!!
//header("Content-type: text/xml");

// Iterate through the rows, adding XML nodes for each
$i = 1;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
  echo $i.$row['name']."<br>";  // names correctly displayed
  $node = $dom->createElement("marker");
  $newnode = $parnode->appendChild($node);
  $newnode->setAttribute("name", $row['name']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("address", $row['address']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("lat", $row['lat']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("lng", $row['lng']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("distance", $row['distance']);
  $i = $i + 1;
}

echo $dom->saveXML();
echo "done ".$i;  // Script ends ok $i = 16
```

Everything appears to be working as shown by the echo statements - however, due to the absence of the message header line, no xml is echoed to the screen.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Check this issue about the PHP closing tag "?>" when sending output through http. May that will help

Comment: Thanks user2340218 - following up what you said led me to wondering about the deprecation warning.

Comment: You've basically dumped some code and said "doesn't work". We cannot run the code ourselves because we don't have your server and database. Would you mind editing the question and explaining why your code fails to meet your expectations?

Answer (score -1):

The answer seems to be not to ignore the warnings over deprecated code - i.e use mysqli_  not mysql_  !  This is the reason I suspect that the xml was deemed badly formatted.

Here is code that does not give an error..

```
$con=mysqli_connect("servername","user","pwd","database");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

// Get parameters from URL
$center_lat = $_GET["lat"];
$center_lng = $_GET["lng"];
$radius = $_GET["radius"];

// Start XML file, create parent node
$dom = new DOMDocument("1.0");
$node = $dom->createElement("markers");
$parnode = $dom->appendChild($node);

// Search the rows in the markers table
$query = sprintf("SELECT address, name, lat, lng, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians('%s') ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians('%s') ) + sin( radians('%s') ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM markers", // HAVING distance < '%s' ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20",
  mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $center_lat),
  mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $center_lng),
  mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $center_lat),
  mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $radius));
//$result = mysql_query($query);
$result=mysqli_query($con,$query);

if (!$result) {
  die("Invalid query: " . mysqli_error($con));
}

header("Content-type: text/xml");

// Iterate through the rows, adding XML nodes for each
while ($row = @mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
  $node = $dom->createElement("marker");
  $newnode = $parnode->appendChild($node);
  $newnode->setAttribute("name", $row['name']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("address", $row['address']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("lat", $row['lat']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("lng", $row['lng']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("distance", $row['distance']);
}

echo $dom->saveXML();
```